# Delete from page vs delete from list

Tags: php, symfony

I delete a entity from it's dedicated page using (generated with CRUD):

```
{{ form(delete_form) }}
```

On the index page I have a list with all entries and I want to put a delete button for each one, so in that twig for I tried to put:

```
{{ form(delete_form) }}
```

and I get `Variable "delete_form" does not exist in home/.../`

```
{{ path('test_delete', {'id': entity.id}) }}
```

Where `test_delete` is the name route for my delete action. This works just lie "see the entire post".

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The form function renders a form, and requires a form object. You get that error on the index page because your delete_form object isn't available there. It only exists on the dedicated page (action) where that form lives.

If you are trying to render the form on the index action (not sure why, but regardless) then you need to set the delete_form variable in your controller on the index action. Symfony is telling you that variable doesn't exist.

If you just want to link from the index action to the test_delete action, then the path function (like you have in your post) should work.

Comment: I tried that but for I don't know what reason, just don't work. Using the function as `{{ path('test_delete', {'id': entity.id}) }}` will do just the action of the `{{ path('test_show', { 'id': entity.id }) }}` wich open the test's page.